# WebFilter's doOnSuccessOrError consumer not working when Content-Length header is 0 [Spring Cloud Gateway]

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

WebFilter's `doOnSuccessOrError` and `doAfterSuccessOrError` consumers not working when the `Content-Length` header is 0.

I have a WebFilter as follows:

```
@Bean
WebFilter webFilter() {
  return (exchange, chain) ->
      chain.filter(exchange)
          .doOnRequest(value -> {
            logger.error("webFilter" + " doOnRequest");
          })
          .doOnSuccessOrError((aVoid, throwable) -> {
            logger.error("webFilter" + " doOnSuccessOrError");
          })
          .doAfterSuccessOrError((aVoid, throwable) -> {
            logger.error("webFilter" + " doAfterSuccessOrError");
          });
}
```

The gateway routes all traffic to a tomcat application using this configuration:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
  return builder.routes()
      .route(r -> r.path("/**")
          .uri("http://localhost:9001").filter(gatewayFilter()))
      .build();
}
```

I have these three endpoints on spring boot tomcat application:

```
@GetMapping("/redirect")
public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingRedirectPrefix(ModelMap model) {
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://google.com", model);
}

@GetMapping("/empty-response")
public ResponseEntity<Void> responseEntity() {
  return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}

@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<String> string() {
  return ResponseEntity.ok("foo");
}
```

Request through the gateway for `/foo` it works as expected

```
[ctor-http-nio-2] GatewayConfiguration  : webFilter doOnRequest
[ctor-http-nio-2] GatewayConfiguration  : globalFilter doOnRequest
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : gatewayFilter doOnRequest
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : gatewayFilter doOnSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : globalFilter doOnSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : globalFilter doAfterSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : gatewayFilter doAfterSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-2] GatewayConfiguration  : webFilter doOnSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-2] GatewayConfiguration  : webFilter doAfterSuccessOrError
```

For `/empty-response`

```
[ctor-http-nio-4] GatewayConfiguration  : webFilter doOnRequest
[ctor-http-nio-4] GatewayConfiguration  : globalFilter doOnRequest
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : gatewayFilter doOnRequest
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : gatewayFilter doOnSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : globalFilter doOnSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : globalFilter doAfterSuccessOrError
[ctor-http-nio-3] GatewayConfiguration  : gatewayFilter doAfterSuccessOrError
```

`GlobalFilter` and `GatewayFilter` works as expected. But, as you see, `webFilter doOnSuccessOrError` and `webFilter doAfterSuccessOrError` are missing for `/empty-response`. It's same for `/redirect` endpoint.

You can use https://github.com/hisener/sc-gateway-test to reproduce it.

Comment: It's probably not a gateway issue, but a webflux one

Comment: @spencergibb I have tried using `spring-webflux-starter`. It works as expected so I guess it's a gateway issue.